# Averaging a certain number of values from a data and plotting it wrt another set of data

Tags: python, simulation, data-analysis

I have ran a simulation and got a set of data. It consists of three rows. Row 1 contains time row 2 contains energy values and row 3 a specific wavelength.

Now for every wavelength value there are 10 energy values and likewise for each energy value there is a time.

Now suppose I have 10 wavelength for which I have 10*10 =100 energy values. So what I want to do is I want to write a code which first averages the energy value for a specific wavelength and then plots the value of average energy vs wavelength.

I am stuck for almost a week any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for, if not, give an  example of your data.

```
# Dummy data
energy = list(range(0,100))
wavelength = list(range(0,10))

# Compute how many energy values for each wavelength
k = int(len(energy)/len(wavelength))
# Compute average energy for each block of k values
energy_avg = [sum(energy[i:i+k])/k for i in range(0, len(energy), k)]

# Plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(wavelength, energy_avg , '.')
plt.xlabel('wavelength')
plt.ylabel('average energy')
plt.show()
```